# Changing the "expires" header in ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I tried the following, but the expiration is set to 1 minute:

```
app.get(['/css/*','/js/*'],express.static('public',{maxAge:7*86400000}));
app.get(['/fonts/*'],express.static('public',{maxAge:30*86400000}));
```

How do set the expiration time using ExpressJS? In the code above, I tried setting the expiration time to 1 week and 1 month respectively.

Comment: Something like

`app.get('/*', function (req, res, next) {

  if (req.url.indexOf("/js/") === 0 || req.url.indexOf("/fonts/") === 0) {
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=2592000");
    res.setHeader("Expires", new Date(Date.now() + 2592000000).toUTCString());
  }
  next();
});`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use [Express static](http://expressjs.com/api.html), and it's perfecly fine, it's rather powerfull tool to serve static files.

express.static is the only built-in middleware in Express. It is based on [serve-static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static), and is responsible for serving the static assets of an Express application.

Besides maxage support it also supports [ETags](http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2011/03/http-etag-explained/).

Just use it this way:

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: '1d' }));`

Here is the [very good explanation](http://evanhahn.com/express-dot-static-deep-dive/).

Comment: Note that the 'very good explanation' suggests to use 'maxage' instead of 'maxAge'

Answer (score 3):

Use https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static
Example:

```
var express = require('express')
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')

var app = express()

app.get(['/css/*','/js/*'],express.static('public',{maxAge:7*86400000}));
app.get(['/fonts/*'],express.static('public',{maxAge:30*86400000}));

function setCustomCacheControl(res, path) {
  if (serveStatic.mime.lookup(path) === 'text/html') {
    // Custom Cache-Control for HTML files
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=0')
  }
}
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + '/public/css/', {
  maxAge: '7d',
  setHeaders: setCustomCacheControl
}))

app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + '/public/js/', {
  maxAge: '7d',
  setHeaders: setCustomCacheControl
}))

app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + '/public/fonts/', {
  maxAge: '30d',
  setHeaders: setCustomCacheControl
}))

app.listen(3000)
```